# Adding a connection to a sewage ejector tank

Tags: plumbing, product-recommendation, basement-refinishing

In my basement I have a sewage ejector tank that looks like this:

[image: Sewage Ejector Tank]

One connection is the vent and the other is the discharge (mine does not have the third hole you see in the foreground).

What I would like to do is to add a wet bar almost directly above this tank. I talked to the building inspector who issued my building permit and he suggested to install another connection in the top of the tank using some kind of gas tight compression fitting similar to the ones that are already there (screw on each side with a rubber gasket seal). He said that he's seen them quite often and he has no problem with them.

I've been searching for weeks trying to find one of these connections, and I can't seem to locate one locally or online.

What I am looking for is a suggestion for a gas-tight compression fitting that I could install in the top of the tank.

Comment: Contact the tank manufacturer and see if they will sell you one or sample one. Obviously they would have tons of them as you can see from the one they mount on the side of the tank.